# Sizeof() ou strlen()?

Tags: c, ponteiro, char

`sizeof()` ou `strlen()?`

Qual a diferença do uso deles em ponteiros de `char`? Qual é o mais adequado?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sizeof()` retorna o numero de bytes da string completa.

`strlen()` retorna o número de caracteres dessa String

Ao executar o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char c[10] = "str";
    printf("sizeof: %d, strlen: %d", sizeof(c), strlen(c));
    return 0;
}
```

O retorno é:

```
sizeof: 10, strlen: 3
```

Ou seja: a string tem 10 bytes alocados (`c[10]`), mas só está usando 3 caracteres (`"str"`).

Espero ter esclarecido sua dúvida.

Answer (score 11):

[`sizeof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) é um **operador** e retorna a quantidade de bytes de um objeto ou tipo. Não é adequado para ver o tamanho de uma *string*. Se a *string* está representada por um ponteiro, o tamanho será do ponteiro e não do texto. Se for por um *array* mostrará sempre um resultado equivocado, pelo menos porque considerará o caractere nulo de término do texto, pode ser pior se o término ocorrer antes do último byte do *array*, ou pode ser que a *string* tenha sido atribuída e tenha ultrapassado o limite do *array*.

Não pode confundir um *array* de `char` com uma *string*. Parece ser a mesma coisa, mas não é.

[`strlen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) é uma **função** contida em `string.h` que contas quantos caracteres - que equivalem a bytes - em uma sequência passada para ela através de uma referência até achar um caractere nulo `\0`. [Não deve abusar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).