# Sempre que vou varrer um string em C devo usar o "strlen()", certo?

Tags: c, string, desempenho

É comum ver em execícios de C que as pessoas precisam analisar e/ou manipular o conteúdo de uma *string*, aí precisamos ter certeza que não vai ultrapassar o limite dela. É muito comum fazer um `for` que vai de 0 até `strlen() - 1`, afinal essa é a função que [pega a quantidade de caracteres da *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143457/101). Em toda linguagem é assim (a não ser que tenha um `foreach`).

Existe algum problema em fazer assim? Tem forma melhor?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A pergunta *linkada* tem a definição do [`strlen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen). Essa função conta quantos caracteres a *string* tem. Se é só isso que deseja, então ela pode ser usada, foi feita pra isso. Mas só use quando esse número é o que deseja. Sempre que o desejado for varrer a *string* potencialmente até o seu fim ela não deve ser usada, não deve pegar a quantidade de caracteres da *string* para limitar até onde ir, essa informação não é necessária.

Na verdade ela é ruim para o desempenho da aplicação. Em um exercício tudo bem usar, mas em aplicações reais não deve ser usada. Tem que ser criativo e usar uma outra forma com melhor desempenho.

C não armazena o tamanho da *string*, complicaria um pouco ou desperdiçaria memória fazer isso. Lembre-se que há décadas atrás a memória era muito escassa. A solução foi apenas colocar um caractere no final da *string* (`\0`) para indicar que ela terminou. Assim garante-se que qualquer *string* possa ser representada e apenas um byte de *overhead* é necessário para indicar seu fim.

Qual é o problema disso? Enquanto linguagens que armazenam o tamanho junto do texto podem dizer o tamanho da *string* com [complexidade O(1)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101), já que basta ler o cabeçalho da *string* e já tem a informação, em C temos complexidade O(n), ou seja, tem que ler toda a *string*, ir contando para obter seu tamanho.

Uma implementação ingênua da função seria:

```
size_t strlen (char *str) {
    size_t len = 0;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        str++;
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

A [implementação real chega ser mais complicada](http://www.stdlib.net/%7Ecolmmacc/strlen.c.html).

Usar um `strlen()` como limite em um `for` quase certamente é um erro porque ele fará a leitura de toda a *string* para achar o tamanho toda vez que precisar desse número e potencialmente vai ler toda a *string* para executar o que deseja. É trabalho duplicado.

Alguém pode estar pensando que basta tirar o `strlen()` de dentro do `for`, assim só lê uma vez. Mas não é solução, ainda que possa melhorar um pouco.

É **possível** que algum compilador faça uma otimização e resolva isso sozinho. Mas até duvido por uma razão básica. C tem *strings* mutáveis, portanto o tamanho pode mudar dentro do laço, pegar o tamanho antes pode ser um erro enorme se o laço manipular o tamanho da *string*. Mesmo que essa seja a solução ainda assim vamos varrer a *string* duas vezes, uma para achar o tamanho e a outra pra fazer o que deseja.

A solução é fazer o que está ali na função do `strlen()`. Ande por toda a *string* começando do 0 e vá até achar o `\0`. Não predetermine quando deve parar, deixa a condição simples determinar a parada. O que está fazendo é justamente trazer para dentro do seu laço o que é feito dentro da `strlen()`.

Isso inclusive resolve o problema do tamanho da *string* mudar dentro do laço (provavelmente vai mudar para menor, quase sempre para maior haverá uma corrupção de memória).

Então se você quer saber quantos espaços existem dentro da *string*, pode fazer dar forma mais "óbvia":

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) if (string[i] == ' ') count++;
```

Pode melhorar:

```
size_t size = strlen(string);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) if (string[i] == ' ') count++;
```

Ou pode fazer o correto:

```
while (*string != '\0') if (*string++ == ' ') count++;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Strlen.c).

Não usar ponteiros em C é um grave erro. C não trabalha bem com abstrações, é uma linguagem bruta. Abstrações costumam conter custos, muitas vezes difíceis de avaliar, não faz parte da filosofia da linguagem. Onde existam abstrações, ela precisam fazer de forma que seja intuitivo o seu uso e que não cause custo excessivo. Elimine a abstração, elimine intermediários.

Portando `strlen()` do C é uma das funções mais mal usadas que programação.

Comment: Por que deixar de usar o `for` no último caso? `for (char *chr=string; *chr; chr++){...} `

Comment: (O comentário acima foi meio humorśitico/+ acrescentar usos criativos do for) - esse é mais sério - vale acescentar que alguns dos textos que avisam para *sempre* verificar o tamanho de uma string antes de usa-la, estão preocupados coma questão de segurnaça - uma vez que se o marcador de final de string não estiver lá, o programa sai olhando regiões da memória fora do contexto. Isso pode levar a um segfault, ou a falhas de segurança graves. 
A recomentação é usar funções que permitam especificar um tamanho máximo da string - como `strnlen` em vez de `strlen`.

Comment: @jsbueno poderia, claro, o importante aí é não usar p `strlen()`. Essa coisa de sempre verificar o tamanho depende muito. Como verificar o tamanho? Fazendo exatamente isso. A pergunta é justamente sobre esse assunto. Se não tiver um marcador de final de *string* como saber qual é o tamanho? Já enroscou. Pode ser que a pessoa guarde esse tamanho? Sim, claro, mas aí não é a forma *string* padrão do C. O `strnlen` faz sentido em contextos muito específicos. Na maior parte das vezes se ele pode ser aplicado, você não precisa dele. Como eu disse foi uma péssima ideia do C fazer *string* desse jeito