# Cifra de César - problema com letras e espaços

Tags: c, string, algoritmo, caracteres

Estou fazendo um exercício sobre a cifra de césar tabela abaixo:

[image: Cifra de César]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
  char frase[200];
  
  printf("String: ");
  gets(frase);
  
  for(int i=0; i < strlen(frase); i++){
     
   if(frase[i] == 'x')
     frase[i] = 'A';
   if(frase[i] == 'y')
     frase[i] = 'B';
   if(frase[i] == 'z')
     frase[i] = 'C';

     frase[i] = frase[i] + 3;
  }
  
  printf("String: %s", frase);
}
```

Problemas:

1. Se eu tentar converter as letras 'XYZ' não é possível aparece '[/]
   Obs.: Tentei incluir if() para caso frase[i] == 'y' ele iria armazenas a letra 'B' no caso, porém não funcionou.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Quando uso espaços aparece # no lugar deles.

Comment: Tente dizer qual o objetivo, as informações estão muito jogadas pra dar pra entender. Nem sei bem qual é o problema. Seria apenas fazer todas as letras valerem 3 unidades deslocadas? O problema é só nos últimos? Mostre o que tentou e não funcionou. Quer impedir o uso de espaços ou outros caracteres? Caso não, qual o critério pra lidar com eles?

Comment: A pessoa escreve algo e as letras irão valer aquelas de baixo conforme a tabela, sim o problema é somente nos últimos, não quero impedir o uso de espaço só não quero que no lugar do espaço apareça a # (seja espaço mesmo)

Comment: Pelo que entendi você está querendo fazer o XYZ se tornarem ABC, como vi na descrição  cifra de césar, o que está acontecendo é ao você realizar (+ 3) você está somando o número de acordo com a tabela ANSI, assim se você de uma olhada nela, o código para Y é diferente para y, assim sua lógica do if não funcionou. Dê uma olhada na tabela ASCII e você vai perceber que os próximos valores depois de Z é [\\]. Você pode incluir uma lógica que ao chegar nas últimas letras (X,Y,Z,x,y,z) ele sobrescrever pelas (A,B,C,a,b,c). Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ainda falta saber o que fazer se for digitado algo fora desta faixa e o que fez no `if` que não deu certo.

Comment: Irei acrescentar no código os ´´if´´ que usei,ele altera os valores porém é feito de novo a alteração desta forma: X > A > D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se entendi o problema, precisa fazer exceção para os últimos caracteres. Aproveitei para descartar algo fora do que é esperado.

Fiz o código mais idiomático C andando um ponteiro em vez de pegar o seu tamanho. [Não use o `strlen()` onde não precisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101).

Se usar outro mecanismo de entrada de dados como o [`fgets()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101) vai ler os dados de forma mais adequada, incluindo espaço. `Scanf()` serve apenas pra testes e uso trivial.

Fiz conforme o enunciado, se outros caracteres precisam ser tratados precisa mexer um pouco no código para acrescentá-los. Não tem um critério claro do que fazer nos casos de existirem caracteres que saim da faixa enunciada, eu optei por deixar como está.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char frase[200];
    printf("String: ");
    scanf("%200s", frase);
    for (char *i = frase; *i != '\0'; i++) *i = *i < 'A' || *i > 'Z' ? *i : (((*i - 65) + 3) % 26)  + 65;
    printf("String: %s", frase);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Q2vo75). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/trfiaykx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/EncodeString.c).

Se quiser fazer não idiomático, tem como, funciona, tecnicamente não está errado, mas não é assim que se faz em C. Se for pra fazer desta forma é melhor usar outra linguagem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char frase[200];
    printf("String: ");
    scanf("%200s", frase);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(frase); i++) {
        if (frase[i] >= 'A' && frase[i] <= 'Z') { //só altera se estiver na faixa correta
            if (frase[i] > 'W') { //trata os casos que precisam girar a tabela
                frase[i] += -23;
            } else {
                frase[i] += 3;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("String: %s", frase);
}
```

[Botei no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/5fzIX1), mas preferia não ter escrito assim.

Comment: Ficou difícil par eu entender o que tá acontecendo esses * e < ? :

Comment: @WSS fiz uma  versão pior, mas mais simples para você entender. Se está com dificuldade para entender essas coisas provavelmente precisa começar fazer coisas mais simples antes de chegar nesse ponto.

Comment: @bigown Qual o problema desta outra versão? Alias testei ela aqui e não efetuou as mudanças das letras

Comment: @WSS eu vou testar, como fiz na mão aqui, sem testar pode ter algum problema. O problema é que não é assim que se faz em C, pra programa em C como se fosse outra linguagem use outra linguagem. C só é vantajosa quando se usa ela direito, caso contrário, funciona, mas você fica com as desvantagens de C, que são muitas, e não ganha as vantagens dela, que são importantes.

Comment: @bigown por que não utilizar o operador módulo `%` para limitar a soma?

Comment: @mercador melhorei.

Comment: @WSS arrumei aí. Eu não estava pegando o elemento do *array*.

Comment: @bigown seria interessante mencionar a tabela ASCII para explicar a soma e subtração do número 65. Senão dá a impressão de ser um número mágico. Assim como a escolha do número 26 para usar o operador módulo, embora este seja mais claro o porquê.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que uma forma mais fácil de explicar seria:

```
int main(){

  char frase[200];

  strncpy(frase, "SUA FRASE QUALQUER", 200);

  for(int i=0; i < strlen(frase); i++){

      if(frase[i] >= 65 && frase[i] <= 90){

        frase[i] = (((frase[i] - 65) + 3) % 26)  + 65;

      }else{
          frase[i] = 32;
      }

  }

  printf("String: %s", frase);
}
```

[Teste isto.](http://ideone.com/gxik13)

Todas as letras maiúsculas suportadas no ASCII então entre 65 e 90, em decimal, por isso é usado o `if(frase[i] >= 65 && frase[i] <= 90){`, se não ele trocará para um espaço, no `else{}`.

---

```
frase[i] = (((frase[i] - 65) + 3) % 26)  + 65;
```

A cifra de césar por si é basicamente mover o alfabeto, por 3 caracteres.

O problema é que o ASCII o `A` é 65. Por isso usei o `(frase[i] - 65)`, dessa forma o `A` ficará `0`, porque `65 - 65`. Depois é somado a *"chave"*, dessa forma `0 + 3`, então é feito o resto da divisão pelo número de caracteres do alfabeto `3 % 26`, que dará `3` e depois é somado com `65`, assim dará `68` que é o `D` no ASCII.

Caso fosse `Z` ficaria exatamente `90 - 65`, depois `25 + 3` e então faria o `28 % 26` que resultará em `2`. Logo o `Z` virará um `C`, afinal é o resultado de `65 + 2`.

Comment: É muito menos passível de erro se você usar as literais de caractere `'A'` e `'Z'` em vez do seus valores ASCII 65 e 90, e para o compilador tanto faz.

Answer (score 3):

Com base no artigo da [wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_C%C3%A9sar), implementei as funções de `cifragem` e `decifragem` a partir de uma `chave`, representada por um valor inteiro.

Repare que a cifragem e a decifragem consideram apenas letras, ignorando todos os outros tipos de caracteres.

Segue o Código Testado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void cifrar( char * saida, const char * entrada, int chave )
{
    int i = 0;
    int tam = strlen(entrada);

    for( i = 0; i <= tam; i++ )
    {
        if( (entrada[i] >= 'a') && (entrada[i] <= 'z') )
        {
            saida[i] = (((entrada[i] - 'a') + chave) % 26) + 'a';
        }
        else if( (entrada[i] >= 'A') && (entrada[i] <= 'Z') )
        {
            saida[i] = (((entrada[i] - 'A') + chave) % 26) + 'A';
        }
        else
        {
            saida[i] = entrada[i];
        }

    }
}


void decifrar( char * saida, const char * entrada, int chave )
{
    int ch = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int tam = strlen(entrada);

    for( i = 0; i <= tam; i++ )
    {
        if( (entrada[i] >= 'a') && (entrada[i] <= 'z') )
        {
            ch = (entrada[i] - 'a') - chave;
            if( ch < 0 ) ch += 26;
            saida[i] = ch + 'a';
        }
        else if( (entrada[i] >= 'A') && (entrada[i] <= 'Z') )
        {
            ch = (entrada[i] - 'A') - chave;
            if( ch < 0 ) ch += 26;
            saida[i] = ch + 'A';
        }
        else
        {
            saida[i] = entrada[i];
        }

    }
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char original[] = "Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes!";

    char cifrado[100] = {0};
    char decifrado[100] = {0};

    cifrar( cifrado, original, 3 );
    decifrar( decifrado, cifrado, 3 );

    printf( "Original: %s\n", original );
    printf( "Cifrado: %s\n", cifrado );
    printf( "Decifrado: %s\n", decifrado );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Testando:

```
$ ./cesar
Original: Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes!
Cifrado: Xp shtxhqr mdexwl ahuhwd ylx ghc fhjrqkdv iholchv!
Decifrado: Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes!
```

Answer (score 2):

Você deveria escrever seu condicional de maneira diferente

```
if(frase[i] == 'x')
     frase[i] = 'A';
else if(frase[i] == 'y')
    frase[i] = 'B';
else if(frase[i] == 'z')
    frase[i] = 'C';
else
    frase[i] = frase[i] + 3;
```

Dessa maneira o incremento só será feito se as letras forem diferentes de `x`, `y` e `z`.

De acordo com a sua imagem da tabela de conversão da Cifra de César, espaços em branco podem ser desconsiderados. Utilizando `scanf("%200s", frase);` como o [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/Maniero) sugeriu resolve o problema

Comment: desta forma ficou mais próximo ao que já estava fazendo mesmo