# Intercalar duas strings em um vetor

Tags: c, concatenação-de-string

```
/**
    5. Faça um programa que receba 2 strings (A e B) e 
    retorne uma terceira string (C) formada pelos caracteres de A e B intercalados. 
    Ex.: Se A='Quarta' e B='Segunda', a resposta deve ser 'QSueagrutnada'
**/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){
    char s1[30], s2[30], s3[60];
    int i=0, tamanho=0;

    printf("String 1: ");
    scanf(" %s", s1);

    printf("String 2: ");
    scanf(" %s", s2);

    tamanho = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);

    for(i; i < tamanho; i++){
        if(s3[i]%2 == 0){
            s3[i] = s1[i];
        }else{
            s3[i] = s2[i];
        }
    }

    printf(" %s", s3);
}
```

O resultado pro que fiz até o momento é esse, eu pensei - Vou concatenar uma letra na posição par e outra letra na posição ímpar mas na lógica não ficou como imaginei

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que em C eu aprendi sobre a função `strcat()`, porém não sei aplicar neste exemplo.

Comment: É uma pena que o código tem os problema que eu falava em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213923/101. Se der depois eu posto uma resposta mais idiomática, mesmo que não seja a que deseja, só para referência para outras pessoas de um código melhor.

Comment: @bigown Vício de faculdade, eles me ensinaram desta forma e é como sou cobrado lá :d

Comment: Ou seja, estou te desensinando. Pessoas que não entendem de C ensinando C.

Comment: @bigown Infelizmente..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alguns problemas que notei

1. A comparação `s3[i]%2 == 0` está errada. Para saber se a posição da string resultante é par ou ímpar faça `i % 2 == 0`
2. `s1[i]` e `s2[i]` não deveriam usar `i` como índice. `i` é incrementado a cada laço e representa o índice da string resultante. Isso significa que você vai pular um caractere de cada string por conta da verificação da paridade, gerando um resultado errado. Ao invés disso, mantenha índices individuais para a primeira e segunda string.
3. É necessário verificar se o índice das duas strings não ultrapassam os seus respectivos tamanhos.

Considerando os pontos que citei acima, as mudanças deixariam o código assim:

```
for (i; i < tamanho; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0 && indiceString1 < tamanhoString1) {
        s3[i] = s1[indiceString1++];
    } else if (indiceString2 >= tamanhoString2) {
        s3[i] = s1[indiceString1++];
    }
    else {
        s3[i] = s2[indiceString2++];
    }
}
```

Exemplo online [aqui](https://repl.it/IyIn/1).

Comment: Devo dizer que suas condicionais me deixaram confuso... mas sim, está mais do que certo

Answer (score 2):

Que tal uma função específica para o seu caso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char * intercalar( char * s, const char * a, const char * b )
{
    int i = 0;
    int lena = strlen(a);
    int lenb = strlen(b);
    int len = lena + lenb;

    for( i = 0; i < lena; i++ )
        s[ i * 2 ] = a[i];

    for( i = 0; i < lenb; i++ )
        s[ 1 + i * 2 ] = b[i];

    s[ len ] = 0;

    return s;
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    char * a = "Quarta";
    char * b = "Segunda";
    char saida[100] = {0};

    intercalar( saida, a, b );

    printf("a = %s\n", a );
    printf("b = %s\n", b );
    printf("saida = %s\n", saida );

    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
$ ./intercalar 
a = Quarta
b = Segunda
saida = QSueagrutnad
```

Comment: Perdeu o último caracter da segunda. Creio que sua solução só funcione para strings de mesmo tamanho, ou para o caso em que `len(a) = len(b)+1`

Answer (score 1):

Opa! o erro está nos índices que você está passando nos arrays s1 e s2. A cada loop uma letra é deixada para trás. Para corrigir isso você deve atribuir um índice diferente para cada variável s1 e s2. Segue o código corrigido. Espero ter ajudado!

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    main(){
      char s1[30], s2[30], s3[60];
      int i=0,j=0, k=0, tamanho=0;

      printf("String 1: ");
      scanf(" %s", s1);

      printf("String 2: ");
      scanf(" %s", s2);

      tamanho = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);

      for(i, j, k; i < tamanho; i++){

        if(i%2 == 0){
          s3[i] = s1[j];
          j++;
        }else{
         s3[i] = s2[k];
          k++;
        }
      }
        printf ("%d\n", tamanho);

      printf(" %s", s3);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Creio que sua solução não se encaixe muito bem quando o tamanho das strings seja muito diferente. Por exemplo, `sexta` e `domingo`

Answer (score 1):

Observando o cuidado que o [@Maniero citou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214790/intercalar-duas-strings-em-um-vetor#comment439099_214790) e seus links relacionados, e também as observações da [resposta do @mercador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214827/64969), resolvi colocar uma resposta baseada em ponteiros.

A ideia é navegar com o próprio ponteiro até chegar no ponto do caracter nulo. Enquanto for possível navegar em ambos os ponteiros referentes às strings `s1` e `s2`, navego em ambas. Caso eu chegue até o caracter nulo de uma delas, termino o laço da navegação dupla e passo a navegar em cada uma delas individualmente. Note que, caso `s1` tenha chegado em seu fim, um laço posterior em `s1` até o caracter nulo não atenderá a condição do `while`.

```
void intercala(char *saida, char *s1, char *s2) {
  while (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0') {
    *saida = *s1;
    saida++;
    *saida = *s2;
    saida++;
    s1++;
    s2++;
  }
  while (*s1 != '\0') {
    *saida = *s1;
    saida++;
    s1++;
  }
  while (*s2 != '\0') {
    *saida = *s2;
    saida++;
    s2++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não consegui testar, mas provavelmente desta forma funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    char s1[30], s2[30], s3[60];
    int i=0, tamanho=0, indexS1 = 0, indexS2 = 0;

    printf("String 1: ");
    scanf(" %s", s1);

    printf("String 2: ");
    scanf(" %s", s2);

    tamanho = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);

    for(i; i < tamanho; i++){
    if ((i < strlen(s1)) && (i < strlen(s2))) {
        if((i % 2) == 0){
            s3[i] = s1[indexS1];
            indexS1++;
        }else{
            s3[i] = s2[indexS2];
            indexS2++;
        }
    } else if (i < strlen(s1)) {
        s3[i] = s1[indexS1];
        indexS1++;
    } else if (i < strlen(s2)) {
        s3[i] = s2[indexS2];
        indexS2++;
    }
}

    printf(" %s", s3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sou novo nisso, o meu ficou assim:

```
#inlcude <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string1[100] ,string2[100];
    int i;

    for(i=0 ; i<100 ; i++){
        string1[i]=0;
        string2[i]=0;
    }
    scanf("%s" ,string1);
    scanf("%s" ,string2);

    for(i=0 ; i<100 ; i++){
        if(string1[i]>=34 && string1[i]<127){
            printf("%c" ,string1[i]);
        }
        if(string2[i]>=34 && string2[i]<127){
            printf("%c" ,string2[i]);
        }

    }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seu código ficou desformatado. Selecione o código e aperte ctrl+k

Comment: Aproveitando, procure explicar o que você fez, o que sua solução difere das demais.