# Mudando os valores dos caracteres em C

Tags: c, string, criptografia, ascii

Estou tentando mudar os valor dos caracteres, somando o valor atual mais algum valor fornecido pelo usuário:

```
char texto[7] = "barfoo";
int tamanho = strlen(texto);

for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    printf("%c\n", texto[i] + 23);
}
```

Conforme no exemplo eu tenho como entrada o texto "barfoo" e a saída esperada seria "yxocll", porem a saída que está gerando é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas primeiras letras até saem certas, porém as próximas não saem como o esperado.

Gostaria de saber se pode está relacionado pelo fato de a tabela ASCII ir até 127. Caso seja teria alguma forma de contornar esse problema.

Comment: Você quer só letras? ou números e sinais também?

Comment: Olá Anderson, apenas as letras, no arquivo completo eu já fiz uma função para pular os caracteres especiais e os números

Comment: Então, porque não está pulando os caracteres especiais. O } está certo

Comment: Obrigado Anderson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem a ver com o fato da tabela ASCII ir até 127 (e não 125). Quando você ultrapassa esse valor começa imprimir os valores da tabelas estendida. Na verdade o problema parece ser até mais restritivo do que a tabela ASCII.

Para contornar isso tem que definir um critério do que fazer. Definido este critério deve implementar no código. Programar é mais entender o problema e achar uma solução do que escrever código. Então isso não é sobre saber ou não C e sim pensar na solução do problema. A saída dá uma dica do que deve fazer, mas ela não é explícita. Tem que exercitar a lógica. Pelo que puder observar quando o caractere ultrapassa o limite da letras, ou seja, 122 ele começa fazer -3 em vez de  mais 23. Então pode por uma condicional, algo assim:

```
texto[i] + (texto[i] > 'c' ? -3 : 23)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CaesarCypher.c).

Isto parece a [cifra de César](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213908/101). Veja lá uma implementação completa e note que lá está feito de forma mais linear. Se for isso, é uma criptografia de brincadeira, só para ilustrar com mexer um dado que é ligeiramente ofuscado do seu conteúdo normal. Não interprete isso como criptografia que é um assunto extremamente complexo.

Aproveito para dizer que não deve usar [`strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101).

Comment: Obrigado Maniero, realmente felhei na lógica, mas consegui entender onde estava errado. Cara tava desde manhã analisando o código, e não tinha percebido esse padrão.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece por que você só está "indo pra frente" - seu código não tem nenhuma previsão para voltar pra letra `'a'`  depois que passar do `'z'`.

Para a linguagem C, caracteres e números entre -128 e +127 são indistintos - todos são o tipo "char" - mas o código de `'z'` + 23 é maior que +127 - então você pode usar unsigned char, se quiser fazer a verificação em um `if` só depois da soma. Seu código poderia ficar assim:

```
#define CHAVE 23

int main() {

    char texto[7] = "barfoo";
    unsigned char novo;
    int tamanho = strlen(texto);


    for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        novo = texto[i] + CHAVE;
        if (novo > 'z') {
             novo -= 26;
        } 
        printf("%c", novo);
    }
    printf("\n"); 
    exit(0);
}
```

Esse código funciona para chaves até 26: ao encontrar qualquer código de caractere que esteja além da letra 'z' minúscula, ele subtrai 26 voltando ao começo do alfabeto, e contando a partir dali. Ainda está longe de ser algo ideal que funcionaria para caracteres maiúsculos e minúsculos além de outros símbolos.

Perceba algumas outras sugestões - como por exemplo, separar o valor da chve para um ponto no arquivo em que fica mais legível, e fácil de alterar.

Como nota final - tenha em mente que esse tipo de experiência é *muito legal* para aprendizado de programação, e mesmo para diversão pessoal e de amigos - mas como criptografia séria ele não funciona. Esse tipo de codificação é conhecida como "cifra de Cezar" - e por séculos foi bastante usada - mas com os avanços formais de criptografia no século passado, se tornou apenas um brinquedo, e qualquer profissional da área pode descobrir a chave em poucos minutos (ou menos), depois de apenas bater o olho na mensagem cifrada desta forma.

Comment: Olá jsbeuno's, obrigado. Justamente estou fazendo esses desafios para aprimorar minha lógica.

Comment: Obrigado pelas ressalvas. Vou analisar onde errei e compreender onde posso melhorar

Comment: Na verdade, não é tecnicamente "erro" -estava realmente faltando a parte de voltar para o início. As outras sugestões nem são sobre erros - são coisas que só com a prática você vai adquirindo.