# Como eu verifico se existe caractere especial ou número em uma string em C?

Tags: c, string, algoritmo

Estou confuso na lógica para verificar se possui outros caracteres senão os alfabéticos. Eu pensei na seguinte lógica, mas creio que esteja errada:

```
char nome[30];
scanf("%s", nome);
int especial = 0;
for(i=0; i<strlen(nome); i++{
  if(!(nome[i] >= 'a' && nome[i] <= 'z')){
        especial = 1; // possui caractere especial ou numero  
  }
}
```

A lógica está correta?

Comment: É uma forma, mas pode existir opções melhores, só com esse trecho meio que qualquer coisa pode servir. Também pode estar errado porque a definição está confusa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algumas coisas podem ser melhoradas e comentei no código porque fiz melhor.

De uns tempos pra cá adotei a postura de ensinar programar C em C mesmo. Acho errado a pessoa usar C e programar como se estive em outra linguagem. A pergunta pede o que pode ser melhorado e estou colando isto.

Já falei algumas vezes que [não se deve usar `strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101) quando ele não é necessário, isto é trágico para a performance, ainda mais como condição do laço. Se esse desperdício não importa então é muito simples, use outra linguagem que dá mais conforto.

Eliminei a *flag* que quase sempre é o mecanismo errado. Melhorei a condição.

Se puder aceitar caracteres maiúsculos terá que acrescentar mais um faixa válida.

Na verdade é possível que nem usasse esse contador do *array*, poderia manipular um ponteiro e mudar esse `for` para um `while`, parece ser a solução mais correta para este código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char nome[30];
    scanf("%s", nome);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; nome[i] != '\0'; i++) { //sem strlen que seria péssimo
        if (nome[i] < 'a' || nome[i] > 'z') { //lógica mais adequada
            break; //encerra o laço, não tem porque continuar, achou algo que não muda mais
        }
    }
    if (nome[i] != '\0') printf("Tem caracteres inválidos"); //se não chegou ao fim
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/jd7v6j). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kdgowgrr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CharNotAlphabet.c).

Mantive a condição do código porque não está claro na pergunta se a intenção é diferente disto.

Comment: Muito obrigado @bigown, sempre muito útil :D

Answer (score 6):

Na prática, essa "[idiomática](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom)":

```
(!(nome[i] >= 'a' && nome[i] <= 'z'))
```

Não costuma ser usada por questões de padronização.

Isso acontece pois nem todos os idiomas do mundo utilizam o [alfabeto latino](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_b%C3%A1sico_latino_ISO) em sua escrita.

A interface da biblioteca padrão [`ctypes.h`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctype.h) fornece diversas `Rotinas de Classificação de Caracteres`.

São elas:

> `int   isalnum(int);`: Testa se o caractere é alfabético ou númerco
>   ([alfanumérico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfanum%C3%A9rico)).
>
> `int   isalpha(int);`: Testa se o caractere é [alfabético](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto).
>
> `int   isascii(int);`: Testa se o caractere é um dos 128 caracteres da
>   [tabela ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).
>
> `int   isblank(int);`: Testa se o caractere representa um espaço em
>   branco (espaço ou tab).
>
> `int   iscntrl(int);`: Testa se o caractere é um comando de [controle
>   ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caractere_de_controle).
>
> `int   isdigit(int);`: Testa se o caractere é um digito decimal (0-9).
>
> `int   isgraph(int);`: Testa se o caractere é printável. (com exceção
>   do espaço).
>
> `int   islower(int);`: Testa se o caractere é alfabético minúsculo
>   (a-z).
>
> `int   isprint(int);`: Testa se o caractere é printável. (incluindo
>   espaço).
>
> `int   ispunct(int);`: Testa se o caractere é diferente de um espaço
>   ou qualquer outro caractere alfanumérico.
>
> `int   isspace(int);`: Testa se o caractere representa um espaço em
>   branco.
>
> `int   isupper(int);`:  Testa se o caractere é alfabético maiúsculo
>   (A-Z).
>
> `int   isxdigit(int);`: Testa se o caractere é um digito hexadecimal
>   (0-9,A-F,a-f).

No seu caso, a expressão booleana:

```
(!(nome[i] >= 'a' && nome[i] <= 'z'))
```

Seria substituida simplesmente por:

```
(!isalpha(nome[i]))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, eu pesquei sobre o comando isalpha() depois e percebi que seria melhor utiliza-lá mesmo! Vlew pela ajuda :D