# C++ std::string.c_str() sempre retornando NULL

Tags: c++, string

Recentemente fiz uma questão, [porque istreambuf_iterator não funciona no android NDK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/287544/istreambuf-iteratorcharfile-n%C3%A3o-funciona-no-android-ndk), como não tive resposta resolvi averiguar eu mesmo, criei um projeto no Visual Studio 2017, coisa simples, apenas para ler um arquivo em modo binário e mostrar o resultado no console, aqui está o meu código:

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Cart.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::string fileName;

    std::cin >> fileName;

    Cart cart(fileName.c_str());
    cart.loadContent();

    std::system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Cart.h

```
#pragma once

class Cart {

public:

    Cart(const char *fileName);
    ~Cart();

    virtual void loadContent();

private:

    const char *m_FileName;
};
```

Cart.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Cart.h"

Cart::Cart(const char *fileName)
{
    this->m_FileName = fileName;
}

Cart::~Cart()
{

}

void Cart::loadContent()
{

    std::fstream cartFile(m_FileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if (!cartFile.bad()) {

        std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(cartFile)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
        std::cout << "STD::String: " << content << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Const Char*: " << content.c_str() << std::endl;
    }

    cartFile.close();
}
```

E tenho a seguinte saída:

[image: Saída de std::string]

E agora c_str();

[image: Saída de c_str()]

Bom, o que poderia estar fazendo `c_str()` não funcionar com `istreambuf_iterator<char>(cartFile)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples, a [*string* do C é delimitada pelo caractere nulo `'\0'`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101), então se encontrar ele, é considerado que a *string* acabou. Diferente do tipo `string` que tem seu tamanho determinado e não usa um caractere delimitador. Como o que está lendo não é um texto e sim conteúdo binário, é muito fácil encontrar um nulo no conteúdo, e ocorre isto.

Como não há razão para usar o `c_ str()` não é um problema. Na verdade nem `string` deveria ser usado para algo que não é um texto. O erro é conceitual.

Comment: um problema resolvido, agora a questão é, como transformar isso em um unsigned char? tentei std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(cartFile)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
  const int i = content.length() + 1;
  unsigned char str[i];

Comment: Mas o vs acusa não ser possível

Comment: Aí é outro problema, precisaria entender melhor ele em outra pergunta.