# Programa de Substring

Tags: java, substring

Tenho um programa em C que exibe todas as substrings de uma String:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char string[100];

void substrings(string str) {
    if (strlen(str) >= 1) {
        puts(str);
        substrings(str + 1);
    }
}

void todas_substrings(string str) {
    int tam = strlen(str);
    if (tam >= 1) {
        substrings(str);
        str[tam - 1] = '\0';
        todas_substrings(str);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    string str = "UTFPR";

    todas_substrings(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Que tem como resultado :

```
UTFPR
TFPR
FPR
PR
R
UTFP
TFP
FP
P
UTF
TF
F
UT
T
U
```

Porém, o desafio agora é passar para Java o mesmo programa, mas como o Java já tem uma função para isso, fiz isso:

```
public class Substring {

    public void todasSubstrings(String str) {
        int tamanho1 = 0;
        int tamanho2 = str.length();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
                System.out.println(str.substring(tamanho1,tamanho2));
                tamanho2--;
            }
            tamanho1++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Substring sb = new Substring();

        String str = "UTFPR";

        sb.todasSubstrings(str);
    }
}
```

Porém está dando o seguinte erro :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 1, end 0, length 5
        at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at Substring.todasSubstrings(Substring.java:10)
        at Substring.main(Substring.java:22)
```

Qual seria esse erro e como poderia arrumá-lo para fazer a mesma função do programa em C?

Comment: O que você quer fazer exatamente? Não entendi a motivação, tem uma que ter uma ordem para a impressão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você já tem o código em C funcionando, basta traduzir diretamente para Java. Não precisa refazer algo completamente diferente do zero.

Veja a tradução:

- `puts` → `System.out.println`.
- `string` → `String`.
- `str + 1` → `str.substring(1)`.
- `strlen(str)` → `str.length()`.
- `str[tam - 1] = '\0';` → `str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);`.
- `todas_substrings` → `todasSubstrigs`.

Veja como fica:

```
class Substring {

    private static void substrings(String str) {
        if (str.length() >= 1) {
            System.out.println(str);
            substrings(str.substring(1));
        }
    }

    private static void todasSubstrings(String str) {
        int tam = str.length();
        if (tam >= 1) {
            substrings(str);
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
            todasSubstrings(str);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        todasSubstrings("UTFPR");
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/yWIkDP)

Answer (score 4):

O C também tem e mais eficiente do que foi usado, por isso que sempre falo para usar o que tem pronto, mas que seja :)

Java não tem essa ineficiência, mas tem outra.

Não que seja um problema para um exercício, mas é bom saber que, ao contrário do C, terá várias alocações de memória para realizar esta tarefa e não é adequado em casos mais reais programar desta forma. Curiosamente em Java é mais interessante fazer na mão do que usando `substring()`. Mas fazendo o que pede na pergunta:

```
class Substring {
    public static void todasSubstrings(String str) {
        for (int j = str.length(); j >= 0; j--) for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) System.out.println(str.substring(i, j));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        todasSubstrings("UTFPR");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pWf9Us). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ocofyutd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/SequenceSubstring.java).

Se quiser fazer melhor em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[4] = "UTFPR";
    for (int j = strlen(str); j >= 0; j--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            str[j] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", str + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CMnucc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kkulkptr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/SequenceSubstring.c).

Tem como fazer sem colocar o terminador e resolver só no `printf()` limitando ali mesmo até onde ir.

Mas eu [evitaria usar o `strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101) que é ineficiente, neste caso é só substituir pelo tamanho já conhecido, se fosse função eu passaria o tamanho já conhecido, ou usaria uma estrutura que guarda o tamanho da *string* como as pessoas costumam fazer em produção.