# Retorno de malloc() pra ponteiro não se mantém entre as funções

Tags: c, ponteiro, gerenciamento-de-memória, malloc

Tenho esses dois exemplos aqui:

exemplo 1:

```
void copiaStr(char *a,char *b){
    b = (char *) malloc(strlen(a));
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(a) ;i++){
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}


int main(){
    char *a = "alou";
    char *b;

    printf("%s\n",a);
    copiaStr(a,b);
    printf("%s\n",b);
}
```

exemplo 2:

```
void copiaStr(char *a,char *b){
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(a) ;i++){
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}


int main(){
    char *a = "alou";
    char *b = (char *) malloc(strlen(a));

    printf("%s\n",a);
    copiaStr(a,b);
    printf("%s\n",b);
}
```

O primeiro exemplo não funciona, dá erro de segmentação, como se o endereço alocado dentro do método, e atribuído a `b`, não continuasse após o fim do método, mas passei `b` como ponteiro, achei que seria uma passagem de valor por referencia, por que esse erro está ocorrendo? E como fazer com que b pegue o valor de `malloc()` de dentro do método?

O exemplo é simples, mas creio estar tendo o mesmo problema quando escrevo métodos para manipulação de listas.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Exatamente, você passou `b` como ponteiro, só que `b` já é um ponteiro, então você está passando o valor de `b` de `main()` para o parâmetro `b` na função. Você pode manipular o conteúdo deste ponteiro, mas não pode manipular o conteúdo de `b` que continua sendo um valor normal e não uma referência. Se deseja poder mudar o valor de `b` você tem que passar o próprio `b` como uma referência:

```
void copiaStr(char *a, char **b) {
    *b = malloc(strlen(a));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) *(b[i]) = a[i];
}

int main() {
    char *a = "alou";
    char *b;
    printf("%s\n", a);
    copiaStr(a, &b);
    printf("%s\n", b);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/InternalMalloc.c).

Embora isto vá funcionar o ideal é o outro código, você aloca e passar o *buffer* alocado, não deve alocar dentro da função. Inclusive em ambos tem um erro porque não libera a memória. Pra um exemplo simples não causa problema, mas é errado.

Tem mais problemas. [Não deve usar `strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101). E o mais correto é passar o tamanho sabido da *string*, até por segurança, além de performance. O ideal seria usar um `strcpy()` e não fazer na mão, pode até ter otimizações nela e feito de forma mais robusta. Feito isto a sua função acaba sendo desnecessária.

Comment: Sim, é completamente desnecessária pra termos práticos, mas a única finalidade é o estudo. Muito obrigado pela resposta.