# Erro ao chamar função que retorna string em C

Tags: c, string, funções, return

Fiz um programa que pede nome e sobrenome para serem concatenados através de uma função:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    //Declarando Funçãoo
    char retornaNome(char nome[], char sobrenome[]);
    //Ariaveis
    char nome[20], sobrenome[20], nomeFinal[100];

    //Entrando com o nome
    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    setbuf(stdin, 0);
    fgets(nome, 20, stdin);
    nome[strlen(nome)-1] = '\0';

    //Entrando com sobrenome
    printf("Digite seu sobrenome: ");
    setbuf(stdin, 0);
    fgets(sobrenome, 20, stdin);
    sobrenome[strlen(sobrenome)-1] = '\n';

    //Chamando a função
    nomeFinal = retornaNome(nome, sobrenome);

    printf("%s\n", nomeFinal);

    return 0;
}

char retornaNome(char nome[], char sobrenome[]){

    char nomeFinal[60];

    //Calculando tamanho das palavras
    int x = strlen(nome);
    int y = strlen(sobrenome);

    //Adribuindo nome e sobrenome a nomeFinal
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        nomeFinal[i] = nome[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
        nomeFinal[x+i] = nome[i];
    }

    //Retornando nomeFinal
    return nomeFinal;
}
```

Porem esta dando 3 saídas

> ```
> Retorna.c: In function ‘main’:
> Retorna.c:19:15: error: assignment to expression with array type
>  nomeFinal = retornaNome(nome, sobrenome);
>            ^
> Retorna.c: In function ‘retornaNome’:
> Retorna.c:42:12: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast      [-Wint-conversion]
>  return nomeFinal;
>         ^
> Retorna.c:42:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
> ```

2 são apenas um *warnings*, porém o erro no começo eu não achei resposta sobre como resolver este erro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em C você não pode retornar uma *string*, até porque estritamente elas não existem. Você pode retornar um ponteiro para uma sequência de caracteres. Você pode estar pensando então é só retornar um tipo `char *`. Isto é o que todos acham ingenuamente. E há casos que pode funcionar.

Funciona se você alocar a memória no *heap* dentro da função, então o que a função `malloc()` gerar de ponteiro você retorna na função e tudo funciona. Isso não é o ideal porque você terá que liberar esta memória em algum ponto e o ideal é sempre librar a memória na mesma função que você cria, e você não pode fazer isto justamente porque precisa que esse objeto sobreviva por mais tempo que a função. Mesmo não sendo ideal em muitos casos é a melhor solução. Em outros o que se faz é alocar na função que vai consumir de fato o texto e aí a liberação é feita ali mesmo, então desta forma você não precisa retornar nada, você apenas passa por referência o que já foi criado.

Se vai fazer desta forma você pode criar apenas um *array* de caracteres no *stack*. Isto nem sempre funciona bem em todos os casos de códigos reais, mas para pequenas aplicações pode ser o ideal. Como este código abusa disto então deveria ser o correto a fazer, alocou o espaço na `main()` e não deve retornar o dado na função, deve fazer este espaço para utilização sem retorná-la. Quando você passa uma referência tudo o que for modificada nela refletirá na variável que foi passada. Seria algo assim:

```
void retornaNome(char nome[], char sobrenome[], char nomeFinal[40]) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/PassString.c).

E retornará nada, você apenas manipula `nomeFinal` direto aí.

Note que se você tentar retornar um objeto alocado na *stack* de função quando ela terminar este objeto se torna inválido e o melhor que pode te acontecer é a aplicação quebrar, pode acontecer pior como executar parecendo que está certo e um dia dar um erro que não fará ideia do seja e vai achar que o computador ficou maluco quando na verdade é só seu código errado.

Eu poderia ajudar com mais algum trecho de código mas não o farei porque tem muitos erros neste código, pra fazer certo teria que reescrevê-lo por completo, tem muitas coisas aí que não é assim que se faz em C, por exemplo o uso de [`strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101), e tem erros de lógica também. A resposta do Isac dá uma ideia como se faz embora eu acho que tirou uma parte importante do código, porque isto parece ser exercício justamente para manipular a *string* na mão.

Comment: Esta resposta merecia uma pergunta melhor ;)

Answer (score 3):

O @Maniero já focou diretamente no problema e quais os conceitos que tem de estar atento e como resolver. Eu vou focar especificamente no seu código.

- A sua função `retornaNome` devolve um `char`, logo isso não é um texto mas sim uma letra, que é logo um dos erros que lhe dá na compilação.
- `setbuf(stdin, 0);` não é util no seu código a menos que esteja a correr o código num IDE que faça buffering das saídas e entradas tipo o Eclipse.
- A colocação do terminador após o `fgets` deve ser feita com a função [`strcspn`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/) que lhe pode procurar pelo fim de linha, o `\n`, ou o fim do texto.
- Se você já declarou a `string` para o `nomeFinal` então porque não usa-la na função que junta os dois nomes? Isso seria de facto o ideal e segue a linha de pensamento dita pelo @Maniero

O ultimo pormenor é: não reinvente a roda! A menos que esteja a fazer um código educativo.  Apesar do C obrigar a fazer muita coisa manualmente, existem já varias funções que fazem coisas uteis por nós. No seu caso já tem a função [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) para concatenar e [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) para copiar:

Seu código com essas correções e utilizando as duas funções do C que mencionei:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void juntaNome(char nome[], char sobrenome[], char nomeFinal[]){
    strcpy(nomeFinal, nome); //colocar o nome
    strcat(nomeFinal, " "); //concatenar um espaço
    strcat(nomeFinal, sobrenome); //concatenar o sobrenome
}

int main(void){
    char nome[20], sobrenome[20], nomeFinal[100];

    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    fgets(nome, 20, stdin);
    nome[strcspn(nome, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("Digite seu sobrenome: ");
    fgets(sobrenome, 20, stdin);
    sobrenome[strcspn(sobrenome, "\n")] = '\0';

    juntaNome(nome, sobrenome, nomeFinal);
    printf("%s\n", nomeFinal);

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/L8Ez11)

Answer (score 1):

Na função você diz que o retorno é um char, mas deveria ser um ponteiro para char visto que retorna uma string
Como deveria ser.

```
   char * retornaNome(char nome[], char sobrenome[]){

   }
```

Comment: Isto está errado, não resolve fazer assim.