# Ajuda com criptografia ROT-13 em C

Tags: c, algoritmo

Algumas letras da criptografia estão passando do 'z', e indo para símbolos na tabela ASCII, por que isso está ocorrendo?

```
#include <stdio.h>  // CRIPTOGRAFIA ROT13 
#include <stdlib.h> // A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char Palavra[255];

    printf ("Digite a palavra que deseja criptografar: ");
    scanf (" %s", Palavra);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(Palavra); i++)
    {
        if (Palavra[i] >= 'a' && Palavra[i] <= 'z')
        {
            Palavra[i] = Palavra[i] + 13;
        }
            if (Palavra[i] > 'z')
            {
                Palavra[i] = Palavra[i] - 26;
            }
    }   

    printf ("%s\n", Palavra);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Para qual entrada percebeu que isso aconteceu e qual foi a saída gerada?

Comment: Por acaso sua entrada que apresentou erro tem letras maiúsculas?

Comment: @Max comparação entre `char` existe e é considerada a ordem alfabética (na verdade é comparado os valores inteiros respectivos, mas o resultado é o mesmo).

Comment: Não, sem letras maiúsculas... 
A entrada foi: gui //
A saída: t?v  //

https://imgur.com/vja1l5n

@AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Da maneira como você fez ao somar 13 você poderá obter um número fora da tabela ASCII padrão (de 0 a 127) e, dependendo do conjunto de caracteres utilizado, por ex. ISO-8859-1 ou mesmo UTF-8, pode representar um valor inválido para representação de caractere.

Comment: O caractere `'u'` é o valor 117, b'01110101'; quando você soma 13 você obterá o valor 130, b'10000010'. Como está fazendo operações matemáticas, esse valor será tratado como um inteiro e, para o inteiro, o primeiro bit representa o sinal; ou seja, você não obtém o valor 130, mas sim -126. Desta forma, quando você verifica se passou de `'z'` você está comparando se -126 é maior que 122; como não é, permanece o valor -126. Não é um caractere da ASCII, por isso é exibido o "?".

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que existe no site alguma pergunta/resposta tratando isso de forma bem completa, então possivelmente seria duplicata.

Comment: O seu problema tem a ver com o tipo na verdade. Uma vez que você utilizou `char` em vez de `unsigned char`, quando soma `13` no `'u'` que é `117` fica com `-126` e não `130`, e por isso o if que tem a seguir `if (Palavra[i] > 'z')` não é executado, pois o valor é menor `-126 < 122`. Troque o tipo para `unsigned char` que o seu código fica a funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos simplificar. O que deve fazer é até metade do alfabeto deve somar 13, se passar dessa parte deve subtrair 13. Não fica mais simples? Aproveitei e [melhorei a performance eliminando um *loop* sem necessidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char palavra[255];
    printf("Digite a palavra que deseja criptografar: ");
    scanf(" %s", palavra);
    for (int i = 0; palavra[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (palavra[i] >= 'a' && palavra[i] < 'n') palavra[i] += 13;
        else if (palavra[i] >= 'n' && palavra[i] <= 'z') palavra[i] -= 13;
    }   
    printf("\n%s\n", palavra);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3hYBoe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Rot13). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Rot13.c).

Comment: Isso mesmo, funcionou.
Porém, você poderia me explicar o porquê de estar acontecendo aquele "erro" no meu algorítimo?

Comment: Um pouco complicado porque você não detalhou o erro

Comment: Olha a saída: imgur.com/vja1l5n