# Contagem de vogais

Tags: c

Preciso fazer um código que receba uma string digitada pelo o usuário, contar quantas vogais existem nessa string e trocar todas as vogais dessa string para uma letra que o usuário definir, fiz quase tudo, só não consigo substituir todas as vogais da palavra pela letra que o usuário digita, qual o erro?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    char ch1,ch2,texto[100];
    int x, tam,i,j,contador=0;
    char vogais[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    
    printf ("Digite uma palavra: ");
    gets(texto);
 
    for (i=0;i<strlen(texto);i++){
        for (j=0;j<strlen(vogais);j++){
                if (texto[i] == vogais[j]){
                        contador++;
                }
        }
    }
   
    if (contador == 1){
        printf ("\n\nA palavra informada possui 1 vogal\n\n");
        }else{
                printf ("\n\nA palavra informada possui %d vogais\n\n", contador);
        }
    printf("Digite a palavra novamente :");
    gets(string);
    printf ("Qual letra voce vai substituir? :\n");
    scanf ("%c", &ch1);
    printf ("Letra que vai substituir :\n");
    scanf (" %c", &ch2);
    tam=strlen(string);
    for (x=0;x<tam;x++){
        if (string[x]==ch1){
            string[x]=ch2;
        }
    }
    printf ("%s", string);
    return 0;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não faz sentido você pedir para a pessoa digitar 2 vezes a palavra (quem garante que a mesma palavra será digitada nas 2 vezes?). Leia a palavra apenas uma vez.

E se a ideia é trocar todas as vogais por uma letra específica, também não faz sentido ler o `ch1`. Leia apenas o que vai ser trocado e pronto.

Outro detalhe é que não precisa criar um array com todas as vogais e fazer um `for` nele todas as vezes. Basta testar cada caractere da palavra e verificar se ele é uma vogal.

Outro ponto é que ao usar `strlen` toda hora, [você está criando um algoritmo ineficiente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/112052) <- leia este link para entender melhor, mas basicamente você está usando o chamado [*Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) (resumindo, `strlen` percorre toda a string para determinar o seu tamanho, e você está chamando-a várias vezes dentro de um *loop*, o que é bem ineficiente).

Sem contar que a própria ideia deste *loop* em `vogais` é ineficiente por si só. Por exemplo, se você já viu que a letra é `a`, para que continuar o *loop* nas outras vogais? Enfim, tanto este *loop* quanto o array de vogais são desnecessários, basta fazer assim:

```
int qtdVogais = 0;
char troca, palavra[100];

printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
fgets(palavra, 100, stdin);
printf("\nAs vogais serão substituídas por qual letra?\n");
scanf("%c", &troca);

for (int i = 0; palavra[i] != '\0'; i++){
    switch(palavra[i]) { // se é vogal, atualiza o contador e troca a letra
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
            qtdVogais++;
            palavra[i] = troca;
    }
}

if (qtdVogais == 1)
    printf("\nA palavra informada possui 1 vogal!\n");
else
    printf("\nA palavra informada possui %d vogais!\n", qtdVogais);

printf("Resultado: %s\n", palavra);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu principal erro foi não ter feito a verificação das vogais após a leitura da letra que seria substituída, exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese"); // Define a acentuação como UTF-8

    int total = 0;
    char x, string[MAX], vogais[] = "aeiouAEIOU";

    printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
    fgets(string, MAX, stdin); // É recomendado utilizar a função "fgets" do que a função "gets" para não ocorrer Buffer Overflow

    setbuf(stdin, NULL); // Limpa o buffer

    printf("\nAs vogais serão substituídas por qual letra?\n");
    scanf("%c", &x);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(vogais); j++){
            if(string[i] == vogais[j]){
                string[i] = x;
                total++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(total == 1)
        printf("\nA palavra informada possui 1 vogal!\n");
    else
        printf("\nA palavra informada possui %d vogais!\n", total);
    
    printf("Resultado: %s\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```