# Função em C que verifica se toda a string é minúscula

Tags: c, string

Tenho que passar para a função minúsculo uma string e verificar se os elementos desta string são minúsculos, se forem deve retornar verdadeiro, se não for deve retornar falso, porem toda vez em que executo ele acusa como falso.

Acredito que eu esteja usando de forma incorreta o `bool`.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Devolve verdadeiro se todos os caracteres alfabéticos da
string s passada como parâmetro são caracteres minúsculos. */
bool minusculo(const char * s){

    bool ts = true;
    int x = strlen(s);
    int cont = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
        if(isupper(s[i])){
            ts = true;
        }
        else{
            ts = false;
        }
    }

    return ts;
}

int main(){
    char str[] = "1 exercicio pratico ";

    if (minusculo(str)) {
        printf("\"%s\" tem todos os caracteres minusculos\n", str);
    }
    else {
        printf("\"%s\" NAO tem todos os caracteres minusculos\n",str);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função `bool minusculo(const char * s)` só devolverá verdadeiro caso todos os caracteres alfabéticos da entrada `s`. Isso implica que basta um caractere alfabético de `s` para retornar falso.

Veja:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


bool minusculo(const char * s){
    //Para todos os caracteres de s...
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++){
        if(isupper(s[i])){
            //...se algum caractere for maiúsculo retorna false
            return(false);
        }
    }    
    return true;
}

int main(){
    char str[] = "1 exercicio pratico ";
    
    if (minusculo(str)) {
        printf("\"%s\" tem todos os caracteres minusculos\n", str);
    } else {
        printf("\"%s\" NAO tem todos os caracteres minusculos\n",str);
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GleamingSameScript)

## Errata:

Conforme o [comentário do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/476026/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-c-que-verifica-se-sota-a-string-%C3%A9-min%C3%BAscula/476032?noredirect=1#comment893773_476032) a função `strlen(s)` tem complexidade de tempo `O(n)`, corroborado nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167528/sempre-que-vou-varrer-um-string-em-c-devo-usar-o-strlen-certo) passado em sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/476029/137387). Isso significa que `strlen(s)` itera por todos os elementos os elemento da entrada e nesse caso específico dobrando o tempo necessário para chegar a resposta.

A alternativa para reduzir a complexidade de tempo é ao invés de medir o comprimento de `s` para iterar percorra a cadeia de caracteres até detectar o fim dela.

```
bool minusculo(const char * s){
    //Para todos os caracteres de s...
    for(int i = 0; i < s[i] != 0; i++){ 
        if(isupper(s[i])){
            //...se algum caractere for maiúsculo retorna false
            return(false);
        }
    }    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado

Comment: Essa solução tem complexidade O(N2), ou seja, uma das piores possíveis. Mas funcionou, as pessoas gostam disso.

Comment: @Maniero `strlen(s)` tem complexidade O(n)?

Comment: Sim, está no link na minha resposta.

Comment: @Maniero veja se a errata está adequada?

Comment: Sim, essa parte está, ficou igual a minha.

Comment: @Maniero, em C não existe outra alternativa O(1) para `s[i] != 0`?

Comment: Sempre pode existir, mas tem que criar, não tem pronto.

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação.

Answer (score 2):

A lógica está errada e o código é mais complexo do que deveria ser.

Se achar um maiúsculo então já sabe que o texto não é todo minúsculo (acho que ´´e para verificar se é todo, a pergunta não deixa claro se é isso), então deve retornar falso, porque está tentando ver se é minúsculo, não faz sentido retornar verdadeiro quando verificou se é maiúsculo.

Para saber se tudo é minúsculo tem que passar por todos caracteres, se ele sair antes é porque não é tudo minúsculo, mas se passar por todos aí sim dá verdadeiro. O código resultava só no que era o último caractere porque a variável ia trocando o valor em cada passagem, ou seja o erro era fazer algo muito complicado, o simples não dá erro.

Também tirei o `strlen()` porque ele já é um laço, não faz sentido ter dois laços para varrer o texto todo, verifique quando chega no fim, [você não quer saber qual é o tamanho do texto, só quer saber quando ele chegou no fim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101).

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool minusculo(const char *s) {
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != 0; i++) if (isupper(s[i])) return false;
    return true;
}

int main(){
    char str[] = "1 exercicio pratico ";
    if (minusculo(str)) printf("\"%s\" tem todos os caracteres minusculos\n", str);
    else printf("\"%s\" NAO tem todos os caracteres minusculos\n", str);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OIIPgb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ytjpkxwk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Filter.c).

Comment: Entendi onde errei, agora ficou mais simples e funcional.