# Converter letra minúscula em maiúscula sem a utilização da função "toupper()"

Tags: c, string

Estou trabalhando em uma função para transformar em letra maiúsculas, porém o meu retomo está estranho. No final está dando o resultado abaixo:

Dados de entrada de palavra:

> ```
> lucas
> ```

Programa está retornando:

> ```
> LUCASÓÓÓÓÓÉð
> ```

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    char convmaiuscula (char texto [10]){
    int i,tam;
     for (i=0;i < strlen(tam);i++)
     {
          texto[i] = texto[i]-32;
     }
     printf("A palavra em maiusculas %s  " ,texto);
     }

     int main()
     {
     char palavra [10];
     printf ("\nDigite uma palavra: ");
     gets (palavra);
     convmaiuscula(palavra);
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem vários erros aí, sem falar a organização e nomenclatura ruim e o uso de coisas que não são necessárias.

Já no código principal se não reservar o espaço para o terminador da *string* vai corromper memória, e o pior que pode acontecer é funcionar, como acontece em vários casos, e vai achar que está certo.

Para pedir dados use `scanf()` ou `fgets()`, jamais `gets()`. Leia [Como ler do stdin em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101).

Para verificar o fim da *string* veja se encontrou o terminador. Leia [Sempre que vou varrer um string em C devo usar o "strlen()", certo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101).

Esse `tam` não faz o menor sentido, parece um código aleatório que foi colocado ali.

Não corrigi o erro de não converter certo toda faixa de caracteres que pode ser digitado porque este é um erro conceitual, assim como a função diz que vai converter algo e acaba imprimindo esse algo também.

Mudei o retorno da função para compilar corretamente já que não há retorno. Se fosse para ter um retorno teria que codificar isso e provavelmente deveria tirar o `printf()`, mas não faz sentido retornar se a conversão é feita *inplace* no original.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void convmaiuscula(char texto[11]) {
    for (int i = 0; texto[i] != '\0'; i++) texto[i] -= 32;
    printf("A palavra em maiusculas %s", texto);
}

int main() {
    char palavra[11];
    printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
    scanf("%s10", palavra);
    convmaiuscula(palavra);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/72OO5h). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/gvhgfvgk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Upper.c).

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback Maniero, em relação a organização, ordenação e indentação do código acredito que foi por falta de experiencia ao uso do stackoverflow ao postar o código idem ao que esta no codeblock. Mais vou me atentar a isso nas proximas publicações. Obrigado

Comment: @ Maniero, acabei acrescentando no código uma condição onde o usuário corrige o problema de colocar uma letra maiúscula junto na plavra.                                                                           
'
void convmaiuscula(char texto[11]) {
    for (int i = 0; texto[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if ((texto[i] >= 97) && (texto[i] <= 122)){
            texto[i] -= 32;
        }
    printf("A palavra em maiusculas %s", texto);
}
int main() {
    char palavra[11];
    printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
    scanf("%s10", palavra);
    convmaiuscula(palavra);
}
'

Comment: É uma boa pedida.