# Função que recebe uma string e a converte para letras maiúsculas dá erro

Tags: c, string

Meu código executa duas vezes o laço `for` e não executa mais nem mesmo o que eu colocar depois da chamada da função `stringToUpper()` dentro da `main()`, ou o que eu colocar depois do laço `for`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void stringToUpper(char str[]){
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(str); i++){
        if(str[i]>=97 && str[i]<=122){
            str[i] = str[i] - 32;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

int main(){
    stringToUpper("All your BASE are Belong to US!");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso não é possível porque está tentando escrever em área estática da memória. Deve [criar o texto em uma área dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/502951/101) e então modificá-la. Ou então copiar o texto da área estática para uma área dinâmica. Ou ainda não modicar texto algum, o que parece fazer mais sentido neste caso:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void stringToUpper(char str[]) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) printf("%c", str[i] - ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') ? 32 : 0));
}

int main(){
    stringToUpper("All your BASE are Belong to US!");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/s9hNQS). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/yxsirlflgi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/PrintUpper.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo feedback, @Maniero. Gostaria de saber, também, o por que dele parar o código no meio do laço **for**.

Comment: Está escrito na primeira frase da resposta.