# "strlen()" funciona com literal mas não com variável do tipo string

Tags: c++, string, char

Tenho este código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int len = strlen("Teste");
   cout << len << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Que gera a saída:

> 5

No código acima, eu estava usando a função `strlen()` no C++ para contar o número de caracteres na string `"Teste"`. Até aí tudo bem, mas quando eu crio uma variável do tipo `string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string nome = "Teste";
   int len = strlen(nome);
   
   cout << len << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

O programa dá erro. Por quê? A função `strlen()` não aceita variáveis? Então eu fui lá e tentei de outra maneira, mudei o tipo da variável para tipo `char`, então o código ficou assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   char nome[10] = "Teste";
   int len = strlen(nome);
   
   cout << len << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

E dessa vez deu certo, ele retornou o número de caracteres da palavra, mas eu pergunto, `char nome[10] = "Teste";` não é a mesma coisa que `string nome = "Teste";`? Por que ele não funcionou com a variável do tipo `string`?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

`"Teste"` por padrão é um tipo `char *`, não é um tipo [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Ou seja, é a forma de C de criar uma *string*, não é a forma de C++. E se vai usar a forma de C então o [`strlen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen), que é uma uma função de C (existe em C++ por compatibilidade, por usar, mas geralmente não é o mais adequado), funciona. `strlen()` espera um `char *`, não um `string`.

A terceira forma é esse mesmo tipo, só que alocando na pilha [como um *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

Se declarar algo como sendo `string` então deve usar o que este tipo oferece, e o correto que é o [`length()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) no próprio objeto.

Então se você diz que o o tipo é `string` tem que pedir o tamanho, o que é inclusive absurdamente mais eficiente que a forma de C. Corretamente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   string nome = "Teste";
   cout << nome.length() << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/o29iax). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/phpuhepesu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Length.cpp).

Comment: Só por curiosidade (e para manter registrado), ao contrário da função `strlen`, que é linear, o método `length` é constante?

Comment: Sim, isso é algo que faz o `strlen()` uma bomba ambulante.

Comment: @LuizFelipe https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/112052 | https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/