# Estou precisando quebrar uma string que recebo e preciso dividi-la. Essa divisão se dará a cada virgula. Estou conseguindo ele reconhecer as virgula

Tags: c, string

O que eu tenho feito até agora é isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 int cont = 0;
 int pos[6];
char buffer[107] = "A!#NanoGsmA)85996161991,B)85996161991,C)85996161991,D)85996161991,E)85986854563,DATA: 09/06/21-09:50:00!!";
char buff[105];

int main(){


    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) {
     
      buff[i] = buffer[i];
      if (buff[i] == ',') {
        cont++;
    if (cont <6) {
          pos[cont] = i+1 ;
        }
      }
    }
      int var1 = pos[1] - pos[0];
      int var2 = pos[2] - pos[1];
      int var3 = pos[3] - pos[2];
      int var4 = pos[4] - pos[3];
      int var5 = pos[5] - pos[4];

printf("%d\n,%d\n,%d\n,%d\n,%d\n",var1,var2,var3,var4,var5);
 }
```

Mas ele não mostras os números que está sendo separado.

Comment: Vc não pode usar a [função`strtok`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)?

Comment: a mensagem pode ser que venha apenas com um numero e o restante dos numero devem ficar iguais.Ex: A!#NanoGsm A)85996161991.

Comment: da certo sim o strtok, mas eu tentei criar algo automático, onde ele conta o numero de ',' e dividi-las a partir dessa contagem. Se tiver uma ideia como posso fazer isso vai ser de grande ajuda.

Comment: O problema é que assim vc tem que percorrer a string 2 vezes: uma pra contar e outra pra dividir. É mais simples percorrer a string uma vez só: começa da primeira posição e avança até encontrar a vírgula, mas já guardando os caracteres em uma substring. Quando achar a vírgula, guarda essa substring e começa outra: seta a posição inicial para depois da vírgula e vai até encontrar outra, guardando os caracteres na nova substring, e assim por diante...

Comment: Sugestão: https://ideone.com/R7SKFc (exemplo simples, que só imprime, mas se vc quiser guardar as strings, teria que adapatar e ir colocando as strings parciais em um outro array, por exemplo). Lembrando que usar `strlen` em um loop não é eficiente: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/112052

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi a lógica do que está tentando fazer em seu programa, mas é algo como um `scanf()` imagino.

Se vai ler apenas uma tabela de valores e **sempre** tem 6 pode usar uma chamada a `sscanf()` e ler tudo de uma vez. Um comando só.

### Sobre seu programa

Talvez concorde que

```
    char buffer[107] = "A!#NanoGsmA)85996161991,B)85996161991,C)85996161991,D)85996161991,E)85986854563,DATA: 09/06/21-09:50:00!!";
```

é ruim de ler. Pode escrever

```
    char    buffer[] = "\
A!#NanoGsmA)85996161991,\
B)85996161991,\
C)85996161991,\
D)85996161991,\
E)85986854563,\
DATA: 09/06/21-09:50:00!!";
```

usando `' \ '` para indicar que continua na próxima linha. É bem mais fácil. E não precisa declarar o tamanho de `buffer` já que o compilador pode contar pra você.

#### usando sscanf()

Veja esse programa

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    buffer[] = "\
A!#NanoGsmA)85996161991,\
B)85996161991,\
C)85996161991,\
D)85996161991,\
E)85986854563,\
DATA: 09/06/21-09:50:00!!";

    char campo[6][107];
    const char* mascara =  "%[^,]%*c%[^,]%*c%[^,]%*c%[^,]%*c%[^,]%*c%[^,]";
    int res = sscanf ( buffer, mascara,
        &campo[0][0],        &campo[1][0],        &campo[2][0],
        &campo[3][0],        &campo[4][0],        &campo[5][0]
         );
    printf( "sscanf() leu %d\n", res);
    if ( res == 6 )
        for( int i=0; i<6; i+=1 )
            printf( "#%d: \"%s\"\n", 1+i, campo[i] );
    return 0;
 }
```

que só tem uma instrução e usa `sscanf()` para fazer esse serviço. Entenda que `'[^,]'` consome tudo que tiver no buffer até mas não incluindo a `','` e o `'*c%'` pula a óbvia vírgula que definiu o campo anterior e assim explica a variável `mascara` usada na chamada.

O programa mostra

```
sscanf() leu 6
#1: "A!#NanoGsmA)85996161991"
#2: "B)85996161991"
#3: "C)85996161991"
#4: "D)85996161991"
#5: "E)85986854563"
#6: "DATA: 09/06/21-09:50:00!!"
```

Não entendi porque está copiando `buffer` para `buf` se não está usando. Recomendo muito usar nomes mais significativos. `buffer` e `buf` é ruim de ler.

E se são strings pode copiar usando `strcpy()` como abaixo:

```
  char original[] = "coisas";
  char copia[100];
  strcpy( copia, original) ;
```

Não declare variáveis fora de `main()`. É um desastre.

Sobre esse trecho

```
      int var1 = pos[1] - pos[0];
      int var2 = pos[2] - pos[1];
      int var3 = pos[3] - pos[2];
      int var4 = pos[4] - pos[3];
      int var5 = pos[5] - pos[4];
```

Isso imagino que deveria dar os tamanhos dos campos. Note que não inicializou **pos**

#### Exemplo

Esse programa acho que faz o que quer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{

    char buffer[] = "\
A!#NanoGsmA)85996161991,\
B)85996161991,\
C)85996161991,\
D)85996161991,\
E)85986854563,\
DATA: 09/06/21-09:50:00!!";
// 23 14 14 14 14 25
    int     pos[107] = {0};
    int     i = 0;
    int     n = 0;
    while ( buffer[i] != 0 )
    {   if ( buffer[i] == ',' ) pos[++n] = i; // conta esse
        i += 1;
    };
    pos[++n] = strlen(buffer) - 1;
    printf("lidos %d campos\npos: ", n );

    // para conferir
    for( int i = 0; i<n; i+=1 ) printf("%d ", pos[i] );
    printf("\ntamanhos: ");
    for( int i = 0; i<n; i+=1 ) printf("%d ", (pos[i+1] - pos[i]) );
    printf("\nOs separadores: ");
    for( int i = 1; i<n; i+=1 ) printf("%c ", buffer[ (int)pos[i] ]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

E mostra

```
lidos 6 campos
pos: 0 23 37 51 65 79 
tamanhos: 23 14 14 14 14 25 
Os separadores: , , , , ,
```

### Uma outra maneira

Talvez seja mais útil ler a string e dividir em outras já prontas para usar...

Considere uma função assim:

#### EXEMPLO

```
char**      quebra(const char*);
```

Que você chama passando a linha e ela devolve uns ponteiros para os campos já separados, e que você pode chamar direto, por exemplo:

```
    char** uma = quebra("stack,overflow");
    
    for( int i=0; uma[i]!=NULL; i+=1 ) printf("%d:\t\"%s\"\n", 1 + i, uma[i]);
```

e ver na tela

```
1:      "stack"
2:      "overflow"
```

E é o normal em C porque é mais prático.

#### como seria uma função assim?

Eis um exemplo comentado em C

```
char**      quebra(const char* original)
{
    const char delim = ','; // fixo
    // agora aloca um vetor de ponteiros para as substrings
    char** subs = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(2 + strlen(original)) );
    const char* p = original;
    const char* pIn = p; // inicio da substring
    int N = 0; // N = total de substrings
    while (*p != 0)
    {   // ate o fim da string
        if (*p == delim) // achou uma sub
        {
            subs[N] = (char*)malloc(1 + p - pIn);
            memcpy(subs[N], pIn, p - pIn); // copia
            subs[N][p - pIn] = 0; // termina a string
            N += 1; // conta essa
            pIn = 1 + p; // inicio da proxima
        };  // if()
        p++;
    };  // while()
    subs[N] = (char*)malloc(1 + p - pIn); // a ultima
    memcpy(subs[N], pIn, p - pIn + 1); // copia a ultima
    N += 1; // conta essa
    subs[N] = NULL; // indica o final
    return subs;
}
```

A lógica é linear: um único loop varre a entrada e conforme encontra os delimitadores vai montando as strings. Note que as strings são cópias dos dados e podem ser usadas em separado, e a string original, declarada como `const`, é preservada.

#### um programa de teste completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char**      quebra(const char*);

int main(void)
{
    char    buffer[] = "\
A!#NanoGsmA)85996161991,\
B)85996161991,\
C)85996161991,\
D)85996161991,\
E)85986854563,\
DATA: 09/06/21-09:50:00!!";

    char* teste[] =
    {
        "",
        "teste",
        buffer,
        ",,,",
        "1,2,3,4"
    };  // uns testes basicos

    // agora testa com todas as strings em 'outras'
    int n_testes = sizeof(teste) / sizeof(char*);
    printf("\n+%d testes:\n\n", n_testes);

    char** uma = quebra("stack,overflow");
    for (int i = 0; uma[i] != NULL; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%d:\t\"%s\"\n", 1 + i, uma[i]);
        free(uma[i]);
    };  // for()

    char** subs = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_testes; i += 1)
    {
        printf("\n==> #%d de %d:\nEntrada:\t\"%s\"\n", 1 + i, n_testes, teste[i]);
        subs = quebra(teste[i]);
        int     N = 0;
        while( subs[N] != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d:\t\"%s\"\n", 1 + i, subs[N]);
            free(subs[N]); // nao vai usar mais
            N += 1;
        }
        printf("\nEncontrada (s) %d substring (s)\n\n", N);
        free(subs); // nao vai usar mais
    };  // for()
    return 0;
}

char**      quebra(const char* original)
{
    const char delim = ','; // fixo
    // agora aloca um vetor de ponteiros para as substrings
    char** subs = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(2 + strlen(original)) );
    const char* p = original;
    const char* pIn = p; // inicio da substring
    int N = 0; // N = total de substrings
    while (*p != 0)
    {   // ate o fim da string
        if (*p == delim) // achou uma sub
        {
            subs[N] = (char*)malloc(1 + p - pIn);
            memcpy(subs[N], pIn, p - pIn); // copia
            subs[N][p - pIn] = 0; // termina a string
            N += 1; // conta essa
            pIn = 1 + p; // inicio da proxima
        };  // if()
        p++;
    };  // while()
    subs[N] = (char*)malloc(1 + p - pIn); // a ultima
    memcpy(subs[N], pIn, p - pIn + 1); // copia a ultima
    N += 1; // conta essa
    subs[N] = NULL; // indica o final
    return subs;
}
// fim
```

Que testa a função com um vetor de strings de teste, que inclui seu exemplo.

```
1:      "stack"
2:      "overflow"

+5 testes:


==> #1 de 5:
Entrada:        ""
1:      ""

Encontrada (s) 1 substring (s)


==> #2 de 5:
Entrada:        "teste"
2:      "teste"

Encontrada (s) 1 substring (s)


==> #3 de 5:
Entrada:        "A!#NanoGsmA)85996161991,B)85996161991,C)85996161991,\\...
D)85996161991,E)85986854563,DATA: 09/06/21-09:50:00!!"
3:      "A!#NanoGsmA)85996161991"
3:      "B)85996161991"
3:      "C)85996161991"
3:      "D)85996161991"
3:      "E)85986854563"
3:      "DATA: 09/06/21-09:50:00!!"

Encontrada (s) 6 substring (s)


==> #4 de 5:
Entrada:        ",,,"
4:      ""
4:      ""
4:      ""
4:      ""

Encontrada (s) 4 substring (s)


==> #5 de 5:
Entrada:        "1,2,3,4"
5:      "1"
5:      "2"
5:      "3"
5:      "4"

Encontrada (s) 4 substring (s)
```