# Como o "free()" sabe quanto de memória tem que liberar?

Tags: c, c++, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória

Quando usamos o `malloc()` dizemos quantos bytes precisamos. Mas no `free()` não dizemos. Como ele sabe quanto precisa ser liberado?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## *Booking*

Isso é detalhe de implementação, mas até onde eu sei todas elas guardam o tamanho que foi alocado antes do objeto. Então o ponteiro que é retornado para você é para o início do objeto, mas não para o início onde houve a alocação para ele. Há um cabeçalho anterior ao objeto.

Esse cabeçalho costuma conter o tamanho alocado ali e pode ter mais alguma informação. É muito comum todo objeto em C ou C++ conter pelo menos duas palavras de cabeçalho (16 bytes em arquiteturas 64 bits). Não é pouca coisa para objetos pequenos. Há casos que isso dobra. É possível fazer com apenas uma palavra, mas algum preço será cobrado, provavelmente em performance e impossibilidade de fazer alguma coisa que normalmente é permitido, talvez acesso concorrente.

Há casos de implementações que o [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) custa mais caro que o [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) porque ele precisa manter uma *freelist* onde vai armazenando os espaços liberados da forma mais organizada possível para facilitar o `malloc()` achar um local adequado para outras alocações.

Um ponto importante é que a alocação é feita em blocos, então não ache que o [`sizeof`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143457/101) de um objeto vai te dar o tamanho alocado de fato. Esses blocos são chamadas de [arenas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/581551/101) e costumam ter 16 ou 32 bytes. É comum precisar de mais de uma arena mesmo para alocações mínimas. Isso tem algumas vantagens, mas pode trazer algumas dificuldade, além do óbvio consumo extra de memória. Um erro de acesso além da área do dado pode passar desapercebido porque ele ainda se mantém dentro da sua arena.

Lembrando que isso pode mudar em certas implementações.

## Liberação

O que muita gente não sabe é que o `free()` não costuma liberar memória para o sistema operacional, pelo menos não em todas situações e não na hora. Essa memória liberada fica como propriedade da aplicação e o `malloc()` irá reciclá-la, na medida do possível.

Eu sempre ensino as pessoas darem um `free()`, não importa o código. Mas a bem da verdade é que códigos simples ou que serão executados por um tempo muito curto, provavelmente por ser um utilitário que faz uma coisa e termina, o `free()` não é tão necessário assim. Ao final da execução do código toda memória será liberada pelo sistema operacional. E isso é até mais rápido que fazer manualmente.

Conheço um monte de aplicação desktop com vazamentos de memória que ninguém percebe, porque mesmo rodando durante horas, não incha demais a memória, incha um pouco, mas ninguém percebe. O que faz muitas atividades que deixam vazamento ou que rodam por dias, criarem situações bem complicadas.

## `malloc()` não costuma ser usado de fato

Na verdade, é comum aplicações reais mais complexas nem usarem o `malloc()` e `free()` originais e usarem um mecanismo em uma camada extra que gerencia a memória de forma mais adequada para aquela aplicação.

## Realocação

Outro ponto é que o [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) não necessariamente copia todo conteúdo da memória. Pequenos blocos certamente copia, grandes provavelmente não, pelo menos não todo ele. A memória virtual é uma lista ligada no sistema operacional, então um `realloc()` pode apenas rearranjar os endereços das páginas de memória nesta lista ligada e não precisa copiar boa parte do conteúdo. O custo não é zero, mas é muito mais rápido que copiar o conteúdo.

## Conclusão

O assunto é vasto. Existem implementações que fazem umas coisas bem esquisitas para atender um requisito. Por exemplo em sistemas *real-time* de verdade, o tempo do `malloc()` e do `free()` precisa ser constante, o que complica a implementação.

Curiosamente se essa técnica fosse usada com *array*, e consequentemente *string*, C seria uma linguagem quase perfeita :P

Relacionado: [Qual a finalidade da função free()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).