# O que acontece se usar "malloc(0)"?

Tags: c, memória, malloc

Pode fazer isso em C? Tem alguma utilidade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível usar sim, e ele até precisa aceitar porque o número que está lá pode ter sido calculado e só por acaso é que é zero.

Claro que uma reserva de espaço zero não faz muito sentido porque nenhum objeto pode ser colocado lá. Mas a linguagem permite o uso e até diz na especificação o que fazer. Não em muito detalhe porque ela [deixa a implementação tomar alguma decisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101). O mais comum é o endereço retornado pela função ser o valor nulo. Mas pode ser um valor qualquer que não referencie um endereço válido da memória para um objeto existente.

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

O mais importante é que o endereço criado funcione quando for passado para a função [`free()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178174/101) sem causar nenhuma anomalia, ou seja, não dê erro e não libere nada. Pode ser que o código nem se dê conta que usou um valor zero ali. E tem que funcionar se ele espera ser assim. Não é para ser obrigado tratar o zero como algo diferente.

Algumas pessoas acham que deve tratar a situação de forma especial para garantir que seja igual em todas as implementações, e usar um nulo em casos assim em vez de `malloc(0)`.