# O que significa arena?

Tags: c, c++, característica-linguagem, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória

Usando o termo no contexto de memória de uma aplicação, o que é, qual a função e importância de uma arena? Onde ela fica alocada? Pode usar só em C ou C++?

Comment: Não seria só a definição do dicionário? "Arena", quando não tem o significado da palavra em português (arena de jogos, arena de rodeio), tem o significado de "esfera" (political arena = esfera política, international arena = esfera internacional). https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english-portuguese/arena

Comment: Mesma pergunta no SOen: [What is the meaning of the term arena in relation to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12825148/2241463)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesmo falando em memória pode ter diferentes definições em cada contexto ou para quem está usando o termo. Já vi ele ser intercambiado com região, zona, contexto, área, *sub-heap*, ou segmento de memória. Algumas pessoas até chamam de *pool*, embora um *pool* costume ser implementado como uma arena, mas pode não ser. Não que sejam a mesma coisa, mas não é fácil achar uma definição canônica.

Certamente é uma porção de memória contínua criada dinamicamente e usada para alocar objetos (pode ser um ou até zero, mas isso é circunstancial).

As arenas ficam no *heap*, embora algumas pessoas possam dizer que a(s) *stack(s)* é(são) uma forma de arena, e talvez ajude demonstrar o que é uma.

Uma arena pode ter um gerenciamento próprio de alocação e liberação, por exemplo pode só alocar e liberar tudo de uma vez na sua criação e destruição, a forma mais comum, ou pode ter um *garbage collector* controlando isso, mas em geral quando isso acontece não é uma arena.

O próprio `malloc()` costuma ter uma implementação que pode ser considerada arena por alguns, já que uma alocação é feita depois de pedir memória para o sistema operacional e ele gerencia *chucks* para entregar para cada objeto que pede para alocar. Isso é transparente para o programador, mas internamente ele gerencia uma *arena*, algumas com gerenciamento bem complexo.

O objetivo da arena é justamente dar controle do gerenciamento a um mecanismo interno, que pode ser criado por você que está programando a aplicação ou biblioteca, de forma mais abstrata, para facilitar o uso da memória.

Algumas linguagens podem entregar isso pronto, outras a técnica é usada para dar mais eficiência onde cria muitos objetos com tempo de vida potencialmente curta, já que ficar alocando e liberando todos eles individualmente seria muito custoso. É comum se usar uma forma especializada que gerencie cada situação de forma mais adequada para aquele caso e foge do gerenciamento tradicional generalizado. Nem todas as linguagens permitem gerenciar a memória de forma tão especializada, C e C++ certamente permitem.

Em alguns casos elas são usadas para gerenciar acesso compartilhado entre *threads*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).