# Por que o endereçamento do malloc() é diferente da stack?

Tags: c, memória, stack, heap

Porque no `malloc()` parece ser alocado 16 bits a mais, e na *stack* a alocação parece ser logicamente correta?

```
int main(){
        #STACK
        char str[2] = "A";
        char str2[2] = "B";
        printf("%s\n",str); # 'A' ( 2 bytes )
        printf("%p\n",&str); # Printa Endereço de 'A' = 0x7ffd5a922c5e
        printf("%s\n",str2); # 'B' ( 2 Bytes)
        printf("%p\n",&str2); # Printa Endereço de 'B' = Endereço de 'A' - 2 Bytes do 'A\0' = Proximo endereço = 0x7ffd5a922c5c
        # A alocação na Stack ocorre de "cima pra baixo" na memoria, então por isso a subtração
        
        #HEAP
        char *str3;
        str3 = (char *)malloc(2);
        str3[0] = 'C';
        str3[1] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n",str3); # 'C' (2 Bytes)
        printf("%p\n",str3); # Printa Endereço de 'C' = 0x559f7e6e86b0
        char *str4;
        str4 = (char *)malloc(2);
        str4[0] = 'D';
        str4[1] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n",str4); # 'D' (2 Bytes)
        printf("%p\n",str4); # Printa Endereço de 'D' = 0x559f7e6e86d0 (Endereço de 'C' + 16)

        # Porque não printou isso? : Endereço de 'C' + 2 Bytes do 'C\0'= Proximo endereço = 0x559f7e6e86d2


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%c3%a3o-e-onde-est%c3%a3o-a-stack-e-heap)

Comment: Leia o [link indicado acima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/112052) pra entender que `malloc` aloca memória no heap, que é uma área mais, digamos, "livre". Basicamente, ele vai alocar onde der, e não necessariamente será sequencial. O fato de ter usado um endereço X bytes na frente do outro não quer dizer que ele alocou X bytes. E o resultado depende de vários fatores (compilador, outras alocações que podem ter ocorrido no meio, algoritmo do alocador, etc)...

Comment: ... Olha a diferença: [seu teste](https://ideone.com/LUhRYo), mas se tirar a parte do stack [muda a diferença entre os endereços](https://ideone.com/6dqXTT), e se usar `free` antes de alocar o próximo, [o mesmo endereço é reutilizado](https://ideone.com/CIqKf7). Basicamente, tudo depende de detalhes de implementação do `malloc`, **nada** garante que será sequencial como é no stack.

Comment: Tem ainda a questão da memória virtual, na qual o programa só vê uma tabela "artificial" com endereços "fictícios", que o sistema operacional sabe mapear para os endereços reais. Ou seja, mesmo que fosse sequencial, isso são endereços virtuais e nada garante que os respectivos endereços reais sejam de fato consecutivos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A própria definição deles já indica isso, são áreas da memória completamente distintas, operados de formas diferentes, então não podem dar o mesmo endereço e o espaço ocupado também.

Em teoria poderia não ter um [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101). Na prática seria complicado liberar a memória depois e até exigiria você controlar isso na mão, dando margem para erro e consumindo a mesma coisa ou pior em outro lugar.

Não vou postar o *link* aqui porque já tem em outras respostas nos *links* abaixo, mas aí precisa entender bem que a pilha funciona de uma forma muito diferente do *heap*, com compromissos diferentes, cada um com suas vantagens e desvantagens, por isso existem ambos. É muito complicado gerenciar o *heap* sem gastar um pouco de espaço para o [***booking***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178174/101), ele precisa no mínimo guardar o espaço daquele *chunk* de alocação, e pode ter até outras informações úteis para o gerenciamento, especialmente em ambiente *multithread*.

Lembrando que isso tudo é detalhe de implementação. Todas as implementações operam mais ou menos assim, mas poderia nem ter *stack* e *heap*, a linguagem não exige isso. Não confie nos resultados, só na especificação.

Para entender melhor:

- [char[] ou *char malloc?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141975/101) (lá tem *links* para mais informações)
- [Qual a diferença entre a função "malloc()" e uma variável criada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/498527/101) (também cheio de *links*)
- [Como o malloc() organiza a memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254358/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

A **stack** é administrada automaticamente pelo sistema operacional, **heap** é gerenciada de forma manual pelo malloc.

Foi usado o  malloc  para alocar 2 bytes de memória  na heap.

```
str4 = (char *)malloc(2);
```

Porem esses 16 bytes apresentado é um espaço extra de alocação que o sistema reservou

```
printf("%p\n",str4); # Printa Endereço de 'D' = 0x559f7e6e86d0 (Endereço de 'C' + 16)
```

Por que **16 bytes** , o sistema faz o **gerenciamento de memória**; precisa de algumas informações como tamanho da alocação, o endereço de início e o  fim até usa **proteção de memória** que evita que os processos em execução não possam ter acesso a locais que não são permitidos , como escrever em uma região de memória marcada como somente leitura.

Não tem  um tamanho padrão de espaço extra reservado, isso vareia de cada sistema.