# De onde vem o espaço na memória necessário para cada elemento em um array de strings em C?

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, memória, alocação

Em C, tem como você agrupar um conjunto de *string*'s, que são arrays de `char`'s dentro de um *array* sem precisar definir 2 dimensões para este?

Para isso usa-se um *array* de ponteiros de `char`'s e simplesmente define as *string*'s que você quiser como elementos dele (me corrijam se eu falei alguma besteira até agora).

Eu consigo usar essa *array* normalmente. O que eu não entendo é a lógica do espaço que cada um desses elementos ocupa na memória. Se cada `char` das *string*'s que estão dentro do *array* de ponteiros ocupa 1 *byte*, como uma *string* com 5 letras pode ocupar apenas 4 *bytes* na memória?

Exemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char* lista[5] = {
        "coffe",
        "tea"
        "soda"
        "water",
        "juice"
    };
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(lista[0])); //A saída gerada foi "4"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não entendeu ponteiros. E já começo adiantando que nem todos possuem 4 bytes, isso só ocorre em arquiteturas de 32 bits, e isso se não tiver algum truque específico feito pelo compilador com alguma opção especial.

Um ponteiro é um valor que apontará para um dado. Por alguma razão acha que o dado fica no local do ponteiro. Todo objeto por referência tem duas partes completamente distintas, o valor em si que fica em algum lugar da memória e o ponteiro que referencia esse endereço onde está o valor propriamente dito. È possível vários ponteiros terem o mesmo valor e portanto apontar para o mesmo dado.

Esse dado por estar em qualquer parte da memória. O mais comum são a [*stack* (memória automática) e o *heap* (memória dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Mas existe outra que pouca se fala que é a memória estática (ela não é a *stack* como muitos acham, essa não estática).

A área estática da memória, como o nome indica, não pode ser modificada e ela é organizada de acordo com executável gerado. Então quando seu executável carrega na memória o código e dados contidos nele ficam disponíveis para acesso da aplicação em alguma parte. Entre esses dados ficam alguns literais, principalmente os textos escritos no código.

Então você tem aí 5 textos que vão junto do seu código no executável. Eles estão lá na memória, o compilador reservou um espaço para isso.

O seu *array* tem 5 ponteiros. Note que o tipo do seu seu *array* é `char *`e não só `char`, por isso o tipo é lido como "ponteiro para `char`". Dá para entender que o conteúdo dele é um tipo por referência como eu expliquei antes, e é composto de duas partes? Uma parte claro, é o ponteiro e a outra parte você terá pelo menos 1 caractere. No *array* fica armazenado só o ponteiro.

Para onde esse ponteiro está apontando? Simples, para a área estática onde está cada uma dessas *strings* que estão no seu código.

Quando você pega cada um dos elementos do *array* não está pegando os textos, está pegando os ponteiros, e todos eles possuem o mesmo tamanho (4 bytes onde está testando). Você não está pegando os textos.

E quando manda mostrar o tamanho é claro que é do ponteiro e não do texto, que inclusive se quer o tamanho o correto é o uso do [`strlen()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143461/101), caso contrário não obterá o resultado desejado.

Se deseja pegar o tamanho do texto faça:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char* lista[5] = {
        "coffe",
        "tea"
        "soda"
        "water",
        "juice"
    };
    printf("%zd", strlen(lista[0]));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/j3oRUJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/StrLenc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/StrLen.c).

Assim você passa o ponteiro para a função que sabe como contar quantos caracteres tem nele (vai [até achar um terminador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101)), o que [pode ser ineficiente quando não precisa saber o tamanho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101).

[Leitura recomendada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/321695/101).